# Designing a DSR load balancer

Tags: linux, networking, load-balancing

I want to build a DSR load balancer for an application I am writing. I wont go into the application because it is irrelevant for this discussion. My goal is to create a simple load balancer that does direct server response for TCP packets. The idea is to receive all packets at the load balancer, then using something like round robin, select a server from a list of available servers which are defined in some config file. The next step would be to alter the packer received and change the destination ip to be equal to the chosen backend server. Finally, the packet will be sent over to the backend server using normal system calls for sending packets. Theoretically the backend server should receive the packet, and send one back to the original requester, and then the requester can communicate directly with the backend server rather than going through the load balancer.
I am concerned that this design will not work as I expect it to. The main question is, what happens when computer A send a packet to IP Y, but receives a packet back in the same TCP stream from a computer at IP X? Will it continue to send packets to IP Y? Or will it switch over to IP X?

Comment: if its from a different IP, it's not the same stream. tcp is connection-based

Comment: So does that mean the packet will just get dropped?

Comment: the stream is one way too; sounds like NAT with half closed TCP cons

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out this is possible, but only halfway so, and I will explain what I mean by this. I have three processes, one which is netcat, used to initiate an tcp request, a second process, the dsr-lb, which receives packets on a certain port, changes the destination ip to a backend server(passed in via command line arg), and forwards it off using raw sockets, and a third process which is a basic echo server. I got this working on a local setup. The local setup consists of netcat running on my desktop, and dsr-lb and echo servers running on two different linux VMs on the desktop as well. The path of the packets was like this:

nc -> dsr-lb -> echo -> nc

When I said it only half works, what I meant was that outgoing traffic has to always go through the dsr-lb, but returning traffic can go directly to the client. The client does not send further traffic directly to the backend server, but still goes through the dsr-lb. This makes sense since the client opened a socket to the dsr-lb ip, and internally still remembers this ip, regardless of where the packet came from.

The comment saying "if its from a different IP, it's not the same stream. tcp is connection-based" is incorrect. I read through the linux source code, specifically the receive tcp packet portion, and it turns out that linux uses source ip, source port, destination ip, and destination port to calculate a hash which is uses to find the socket that should receive the traffic. However, if no such socket matches the hash, it tries again using only the destination ip and destination port and that is how this "magic" works. I have no idea if this would work on a windows machine though.

One caveat to this answer is that I also spun up two remote VMs and tried the same experiment, and it did not work. I am guessing it worked while all the machines were on the same switch, but there might be a little more work to do to get it to work if it goes through different routers. I am still trying to figure this out, but from using tcpdump to analyze the traffic, for some reason the dsr-lb is forwarding to the wrong port on the echo server. I am not sure if something is corrupted, or if the checksum is wrong after changing the destination ip and some router along the way is dropping it or changing it somehow(I suspect this might be the case) but hopefully I can get it working over an actual network.

The theory should still hold though. The IP layer is basically a packet forwarding layer and routers should not care about the contents of the packets, they should just forward packets based on their routing tables, so changing the destination of the packet while leaving the source the same should result in the source receiving any answer. The fact that the linux kernel ultimately resolves packets to sockets just using destination ip and port means the only real roadblock to this working does not really exist.

Also, if anyone is wondering why bother doing this, it may be useful for a loadbalancer in front of websocket servers. Its not as great as a direct connection from client to websocket server, but it is better than a loadbalancer that handles both requests and responses, which makes it more scalable, and more able to run on less resources.